# Gridview edit Row going to next page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

> When i am trying to edit a editable gridview by clicking on edit
>   button. (so without inserting data) when i navigate to next page of
>   the grid.i saw that grid row which i edited is being open to edit
>   without clicking edit button. in 1st page(1st image) of the grid u can
>   see that i am trying to edit 6th row

[image: 1st page of the gridview]
[image: 2nd page of the grid]

> in 2nd page of the grid you can see that 6th row is changed to
>   editable mode without even clicking on edit button

**vb.net code**

```
Protected Sub BindGridSubMeter()
    Dim conMRI As New ConnectionMRI()
    Dim ds As DataSet = conMRI.NabersSubMetergetData(ddlBldgId.SelectedItem.Value, ddlRating.SelectedItem.Value)
    TextExclusions.Text = ds.Tables(1).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()
    UpdatePanelExclusions.update()
    With GridSubMeter
        .DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        .DataBind()
    End With
End Sub

Protected Sub GridSubMeter_RowEditing(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles GridSubMeter.RowEditing
    GridSubMeter.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    Me.BindGridSubMeter()
End Sub

Protected Sub GridSubmeter_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e4 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridSubMeter.PageIndexChanging
    GridSubMeter.PageIndex = e4.NewPageIndex
    Me.BindGridSubMeter()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not reset the `EditIndex` on `PageIndexChanging`. The edit index is based on the visible items, not the total.

```
Protected Sub GridSubmeter_PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e4 As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridSubMeter.PageIndexChanging
    GridSubMeter.EditIndex = -1
    GridSubMeter.PageIndex = e4.NewPageIndex
    Me.BindGridSubMeter()
End Sub
```